# Is there any way to get list of files in the same folder as current file (in hdfs), in setup method?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

My java hadoop job get some path as input. I override setup method in mapper class, and I cat obtain path of current file:

```
((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().toString();
```

*Is there any way to get list of files in the same folder as current file (in hdfs), in setup method?*

More precisely, I need to handle following case: folder contains set of files, and each of them contains some code in theirs name, for example:

```
fileName_somecode1.txt fileName_somecode2.txt ... fileName_somecoden.txt
```

Before mapper start work, I need read all files in folder, collect all codes, and then make decision if I need to process current file.

Lets look at simple example:

```
test_1.txt test_2.txt test_3.txt
```

I need skip all files if there are exists some codes which are more and less then current one, so in this toy example test_2.txt should be skipped, because there are 1 and 3 codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Path file = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath();
Path folder = file.getParent();
Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(folder.toUri(), conf);
FileStatus[] statuses = fs.listStatus(folder); // get list of files in folder
for (FileStatus status : statuses) {
    Path f = status.getPath();
    // process file f
}
```